# Facebook permissions to display posts from a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

One of our client had their permissions revoked, because they were to late to update their permissions. So we have to make a new request with a screencast.

The site will display posts from the owners Facebook page - that's it. We have an app with the ID, and created an access token. We made a screencast of how we use their api (show the feed). Facebook declined the request because we didn't display how to login to the site, using Facebook authentication. But we don't even use it.

We are using this endpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{page-id}/posts?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`. Are we using the wrong endpoint, just to display the feed?

Comment: No, that’s the correct endpoint. If you have not implemented login and get your token from somewhere else, then try to make that very clear to them in your review instructions. If they are not willing to accept that - then implement Facebook login …

Comment: Well, we kind of did that. We mentioned it in review instructions. We will try to be more clear. Thanks for confirming at least!